# Empty models in rails runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, eventmachine, tweetstream

I'm using Rails 3.2 and I would like to have a side process monitoring a TweetStream using rails runner, unfortunately my Models seem to be empty until I access them using the debugger. What would cause this? Do I need to reconnect to my database? Is this something to do with EventMachine?

More specifically, I have:

```
charity = Charity.find_by_blah(blah)
if charity.nil?
   binding.pry
   do_stuff
end
```

And what happens is, charity will be nil and pass the check, but when I try running the command `charity = Charity.find_by_blah(blah)` in pry, it returns the correct object. Any ideas? I'm running `rails s` in one tab, and then in another I'm running

`rails runner script/tweetstream.rb`

(Ideally the tweetstream will be a daemon down the line)

Comment: you might need to post some more code, what's in your tweetstreem.rb and the `find_by_blah` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error, I had to reconnect to the DB on init.